# Is it possible to train CNN on 1 column of csv data?

Tags: neural-networks, python, tensorflow

I want to train CNN model on 1 column data, the data was taken from EMG Sensor the shape of data represented in one column such that:

[image]

these data represent the EMG signals,

**column 0 is signals value - column 1 is Class Labels which there are 3 classes**

i want to train CNN with Conv1D on it so, when i train CNN model the val_acc is stuck at some value, I tried to change the model architecture but the problem is still so i think the problem in my data. is there any preprocessing steps should i do before train?

Comment: consider normalizing your values, try z-score for example. Seems like your feature column is always increasing, is that true?